# Display records from database in date range

Tags: c#

I have a number of  1 day events in a database and need to display them from midnight to midnight.. So for example Today's events will expire and not be displayed from Midnight tonight, and tomorrows events will display from Midnight tonight, or just after. I'm using 'DateTime.Today' but I'm not getting the results I need.

Comment: @OP if you want more detailed or better fitting answers than the ones you got you would need to give more infos like how the database is structured (aka how the date field is called), and also if you are using EF or plain SQL,....  and if plain sql what the calling method for the querying looks like. Else only general answers like the ones currently done are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it with a simple SQL query it should looks like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE somecol = CURDATE()
```

where CURRDATE() returns the current date. For example for today it will be 10/2/2015.

If you are doing it using EF you can use LINQ and it can looks like this:

```
db.Events.Where(e => e.Date >= DateTime.Today && e.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)).Select(e => e);
```

I dont really know how you db is structured so I can't be more specific

Comment: That's looking good but I need to display all other future events in database not just today's

Comment: Okay then. I said I am not familiar with your database. If you show your database schema and you tell us what you really need we might figure it out how it is going to look like as code

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Instead of

```
DateTime.Today;
```

Because `DateTime.Today;` will return date + time (12:00:00) which might not select all the record. So better to send only the date and not the time.

Answer (score 0):

use select sql statement to fetch only today records

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE DateDiff(d,dateCouName, GetDate())=0
```